# Writing If-Then Statement in ArcGIS Field Calculator using Python Parser?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser, if-statement

Scenario:

I have four fields: A, B, C and D

Field A is text-based and contains values from '000' up to some number 'xxx'
Field B contains a set of values (also text, but represented by numbers)
Field C contains a set of values (also text, but represented by numbers)
Field D is empty and waiting to be populated

I would like to construct an if-then statement in Field Calculator that does something like this:

```
If Field A = 000 then Field D = Field B, 
If Field A =/= 000 then Field D = Field C
```

I have spent the better part of my day trying to find the proper 'language' to ask Field Calculator, but I'm stuck.  I have 0 programming experience also.

Could anybody show me how this should be set up either in Python?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 8):

Using Python, the calculation would look like this:

For the Pre-Logic Script:

```
def Calc(a,b,c):
 if a == "000":
      return b
 else:
      return c
```

For the expression:

```
Calc( !A! , !B! , !C! )
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply!  I was not able to get this script to work....should it be used in Python or Python_9.3?  Also when I go to insert the real names of my fields, they always have the exclaimation points before/after.  Should they also appear that way in the Pre-logic script?

Comment: In the pre-logic, the variable names are simply placeholders and can be called whatever you like.

Comment: Wow - ok thanks nmpeterson for pointing that out.  Totally worked!  Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic `inline if` is working in Field Calculator expression

`res=(on_false, on_true)[condition]`

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("fc" , "field" ,"(!C!, !B!)[!A!=='000']" , "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was able to -briefly- get your post to work, but when I tried to integrate the script into a larger model it broke down and keeps giving me this error:                                                  ERROR 000539: Runtime error <class 'arcgisscripting.ExecuteError'>: ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset PARCEL does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (Calculate Field).                       Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: `Input Table: Dataset PARCEL does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (Calculate Field)` this error means , i think that the feature class has not been found.