# Reclassifying shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, vector

So I have a shapefile consisting of 1000 polygon records. I would want to reclassify one field "Value" into a new blank field named "New Value". As an example:

```
record = 1; value = 25.6
record = 2; value = 35.4
record = 3; value = 14.1
record = 4; value = 44.6
record = 5; value = 8.7
record = 6; value = 2.1
record = 7; value = 10.4
record = 8; value = 18.3
record = 9; value = 30.9
record = 10; value = 28.5
```

I want all records with records from 0 to 10 as new field with label "rice".  Then 11 to 15 as "wheat", 15 to 25 as "corn", and the remaining unclassified records as "others".

To do this with ArcGIS Desktop, do I use the Field Calculator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to build an expression like the one in [Writing If-Then Statement in ArcGIS Field Calculator using Python Parser?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78352)  You need an if, elif, elif, else statement.

Set your language to Python in the Field Calculator.

Put this in the code block:

```
def rc(f):
  if 10 >= f >= 0:
    return "rice"
  elif 15 >= f >= 11:
    return "wheat"
  elif 25 >= f >= 16:
    return "corn"
  else:
    return "others"
```

put this in the expression box:

```
rc(ValueField)
```

Value field will be the field that holds the values you want to reclassify.